# bash select multiple answers at once

Tags: bash, select

I have a flat file called items that I want to populate a select but I want to be able to choose multiple items at one time.

contents of items file:

```
cat 1
dog 1
pig 1
cherry 2
apple 2
```

Basic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3=$'\n\nSelect the animals you like: '
options=$(grep '1' items|grep -v '^#' |awk '{ print $1 }')

select choice in $options
do
  echo "you selected: $choice"
done

exit 0
```

The way it flows now is I can only select one option at at time.  I'd like to be able to answer 1,3 or 1 3 and have it respond "you selected: cat pig"

Thank you,

Tazmarine

Comment: I'd say it's impossible to do that with `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.  This seems to works as I want.  I want the final output to be comma separated:

```
#!/bin/bash

newarray=(all $(grep '1' items|grep -v '^#' |awk '{ print $1 }'))

options() {
num=0
for i in ${newarray[@]}; do
  echo "$num) $i"
  ((num++))
done
}

getanimal() {
while [[ "$show_clean" =~ [A-Za-z] || -z "$show_clean"  ]]; do
  echo "What animal do you like: "
  options
  read -p 'Enter number: ' show
  echo
  show_clean=$(echo $show|sed 's/[,.:;]/ /g')
  selected=$(\
  for s in $show_clean; do
    echo -n "\${newarray[${s}]},"
  done)
  selected_clean=$(echo $selected|sed 's/,$//')
done
eval echo "You selected $selected_clean"
}

getanimal

exit 0
```

Answer (score 12):

I can offer a somewhat different approach that uses a different selection prompt style. Here's a bash function that allows user to select multiple options with arrow keys and Space, and confirm with Enter. It has a nice menu-like feel. I wrote it with the help of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415155. It can be called like this:

```sh
multiselect result "Option 1;Option 2;Option 3" "true;;true"
```

The result is stored as an array in a variable with the name supplied as the first argument. Last argument is optional and is used for making some options selected by default. It looks like this:
[image: example]

```sh
function prompt_for_multiselect {

    # little helpers for terminal print control and key input
    ESC=$( printf "\033")
    cursor_blink_on()   { printf "$ESC[?25h"; }
    cursor_blink_off()  { printf "$ESC[?25l"; }
    cursor_to()         { printf "$ESC[$1;${2:-1}H"; }
    print_inactive()    { printf "$2   $1 "; }
    print_active()      { printf "$2  $ESC[7m $1 $ESC[27m"; }
    get_cursor_row()    { IFS=';' read -sdR -p $'\E[6n' ROW COL; echo ${ROW#*[}; }
    key_input()         {
      local key
      IFS= read -rsn1 key 2>/dev/null >&2
      if [[ $key = ""      ]]; then echo enter; fi;
      if [[ $key = $'\x20' ]]; then echo space; fi;
      if [[ $key = $'\x1b' ]]; then
        read -rsn2 key
        if [[ $key = [A ]]; then echo up;    fi;
        if [[ $key = [B ]]; then echo down;  fi;
      fi 
    }
    toggle_option()    {
      local arr_name=$1
      eval "local arr=(\"\${${arr_name}[@]}\")"
      local option=$2
      if [[ ${arr[option]} == true ]]; then
        arr[option]=
      else
        arr[option]=true
      fi
      eval $arr_name='("${arr[@]}")'
    }

    local retval=$1
    local options
    local defaults

    IFS=';' read -r -a options <<< "$2"
    if [[ -z $3 ]]; then
      defaults=()
    else
      IFS=';' read -r -a defaults <<< "$3"
    fi
    local selected=()

    for ((i=0; i<${#options[@]}; i++)); do
      selected+=("${defaults[i]}")
      printf "\n"
    done

    # determine current screen position for overwriting the options
    local lastrow=`get_cursor_row`
    local startrow=$(($lastrow - ${#options[@]}))

    # ensure cursor and input echoing back on upon a ctrl+c during read -s
    trap "cursor_blink_on; stty echo; printf '\n'; exit" 2
    cursor_blink_off

    local active=0
    while true; do
        # print options by overwriting the last lines
        local idx=0
        for option in "${options[@]}"; do
            local prefix="[ ]"
            if [[ ${selected[idx]} == true ]]; then
              prefix="[x]"
            fi

            cursor_to $(($startrow + $idx))
            if [ $idx -eq $active ]; then
                print_active "$option" "$prefix"
            else
                print_inactive "$option" "$prefix"
            fi
            ((idx++))
        done

        # user key control
        case `key_input` in
            space)  toggle_option selected $active;;
            enter)  break;;
            up)     ((active--));
                    if [ $active -lt 0 ]; then active=$((${#options[@]} - 1)); fi;;
            down)   ((active++));
                    if [ $active -ge ${#options[@]} ]; then active=0; fi;;
        esac
    done

    # cursor position back to normal
    cursor_to $lastrow
    printf "\n"
    cursor_blink_on

    eval $retval='("${selected[@]}")'
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this helped me a lot :)
[**USAGE EXAMPLE HERE**](https://gist.github.com/sergiofbsilva/099172ea597657b0d0008dc367946953)

Comment: The sheer ammount of knowledge shared in that link is amazing. Thanks for sharing the link!

Comment: Any idea how to fix this to deal with options that exceed the screen size?

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that as such, but you can always record each individual selection:

```
#!/bin/bash
PS3=$'\n\nSelect the animals you like: '
options=$(grep '1' items|grep -v '^#' |awk '{ print $1 }')

# Array for storing the user's choices
choices=()

select choice in $options Finished
do
  # Stop choosing on this option
  [[ $choice = Finished ]] && break
  # Append the choice to the array
  choices+=( "$choice" )
  echo "$choice, got it. Any others?"
done

# Write out each choice
printf "You selected the following: "
for choice in "${choices[@]}"
do
  printf "%s " "$choice"
done
printf '\n'

exit 0
```

Here's an example interaction:

```
$ ./myscript
1) cat
2) dog
3) pig
4) Finished

Select the animals you like: 3
pig, got it. Any others?

Select the animals you like: 1
cat, got it. Any others?

Select the animals you like: 4
You selected the following: pig cat
```

If you instead want to be able to write `3 1` on the same line, you'll have to make your own menu loop with `echo` and `read`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I do want the ability to use 1 3 4 7 or 1,3,4,7 or even 1:3:4:7.  Some lists can be 80+ items large so selecting them one at a time is not preferred.  I’ll have to think about this and post some options.  Since the item list can vary I suspect I’ll first need to define variables for numbers then a way to parse it out.  I’ll update this post Tuesday with what I come up with.  Thank you.